# Configuring a custom port for the 'localhost' redirect URL in Google OAuth 2.0

Tags: google-oauth

I want to configure a custom port for the redirect URL in the Google Developer Console for the class of 'Installed Apps'.

Following the instructions in https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2InstalledApp , it turns out that this should be possible:

`redirect_uri=http://localhost:9004&`

Going to the Console ("console.developers.google.com"), "Credentials", and "Create New Client Id", I cannot find the field, where to enter a custom port number. Does anyone know how to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: For installed apps, the redirect_url is fixed, it can be `urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob` or `http://localhost`, you can not edit in the console, if you want to use port, just use it, like `redirect_uri=http://localhost:9004`, it can work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In fact, The document you've read has answered you question:

> When you create a client ID in the Google Developers Console, two redirect_uris are created for you: `urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob` and `http://localhost`. The value your application uses determines how the authorization code is returned to your application.
>
> `http://localhost` signals to the Google Authorization Server that the authorization code should be returned as a query string parameter to the web server on the client. **You may specify a port number without changing the Google Developers Console configuration.**

Comment: Thanks for helping out, this was not obvious for me.

Answer (score 0):

I tried this idea and it works.
Give consecutive ports or probable ports in credentials as

```
**Redirect URIs**
http://localhost:55738/YoutubeVideoList.aspx
http://localhost:8080/YoutubeVideoList.aspx
http://localhost:8081/YoutubeVideoList.aspx
http://localhost:8082/YoutubeVideoList.aspx
http://localhost:8083/YoutubeVideoList.aspx
http://localhost:8084/YoutubeVideoList.aspx
```

and don't forget to give correct redirectURI with port(anyone above) while calling the authentication process.